# Error when deploying ASP.NET Web API on IIS7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I develop ASP.NET Web API app which is working fine when I run it under Visual Studio 2010. It runs and works just perfect. But when I deploy it (xcopy) to the web server it crashes and doesn’t run:

[image: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep. System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpRoutingDispatcher.SendAsync]

I’ve tried so far: Re-registering ASP.NET with IIS (aspnet_regiis.exe  -i) for both x32 and x64 versions of .NET
Deploying the application using VS 2010 Build deployment package command and then exporting this package into IIS.

Any thoughts?

P.S. Other ASP.NET 4.0 applications (not MVC/Web API) are working just fine on the same server.

UPDATE: Part of my web.config (excluding connection strings and app settings)

```
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
<authentication mode="None" />
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
  </providers>
</sessionState> </system.web>  



  <system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>  </system.webServer>


<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>  </runtime>  

<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />  </entityFramework>
```

Comment: Many issues can produce this problem. Check if you are using session. If yes, post your configuration file. If not, try to post more information about your code

Comment: I'm using session. I'll post part of my web.config now. It just a standrd web.config generated for me by Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I am 90% sure that the problem here is related to your custom message handlers. I believe this is a bug but the team insisted that this was not. Not sure how they will approach it. Here is the drill:

If you create the response from scratch inside any of your message handlers, it doesn't carry the `RequestMessage` property by default obviously. So, it fails miserably with the famous *"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."* error as soon as it's used. For example, the blow code, which sets the `RequestMessage` property of the `HttpResponseMessage`, solves the problem but I believe this should be done by the framework:

```
public class TerminatingMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler {

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken) {

        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.RequestMessage = request;
        return Task.FromResult(response).ContinueWith(task => {

            var responseMsg = task.Result;

            var httpContext = responseMsg.RequestMessage.Properties["MS_HttpContext"] as HttpContextWrapper;
            if (httpContext != null)
                httpContext.Response.Headers.Remove("Server");

            return responseMsg;
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the bug report: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/408 If this is the case here for you, you may vote and leave a comment there if you want this to be fixed, too.